# How to access/edit elements in Pandas Dataframe by label without index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe without a meaningful index as the following.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':
    ['orange','banana','lemon','mango','apple'],
    'price':
    [2,3,7,21,11],
    'stock':
    ['Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes']
})

     name  price stock
0  orange      2   Yes
1  banana      3    No
2   lemon      7   Yes
3   mango     21    No
4   apple     11   Yes
```

I'd like to obtain the price of the bananas. I try with `df.at[df['name'] == 'banana', 'price']` But I get `TypeError`. Surprisingly, I can assign values: `df.at[df['name'] == 'banana', 'price'] = 7` works. Why this difference?

Another thing that puzzles me is that if I use `loc` it works, but it doesn't return the bare value.

For a bit of context, what I'm trying to do is to add new records to a Dataframe that are based on existing records, therefore I need to access to these values and assign (a function of) them to the new records. For example, I'd like to get a new record where the prize of `banana deluxe` is 1 more than that of `banana`.

```
     name  price stock
0          orange      2   Yes
1          banana      3    No
2           lemon      7   Yes
3           mango     21    No
4           apple     11   Yes
5   banana deluxe      4   Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `df.at[df['name'] == 'banana', 'price']`
You should do `df.at[df['name'] == 'banana']['price']` to get the price.

The reason you get a type error is because:

`df['name']` is a string.
`'banana', 'price'` is a `tuple`.

Checking `df['name'] == 'banana', 'price'` is checking a string against a tuple.
Hence the typerror

Comment: But then how come the assignation works? And why the .loc version also works?

Comment: I looked into it a bit and couldn't find the exact reasoning.
I see that it is raising an error if the key is a tuple. But, it is very similar logic for both `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.
Here is the pandas code base in case you want to do a deep dive:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d733368ad068e8405576fe151cc4ee39c00bff7b/pandas/core/series.py#L922